# 'A decapitated head' from the Huffington Post sounds strange to me

Tags: grammar, adjectives, word-usage, sentence-structure

The [headlines on the Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2014/08/12/grandfather-australian-boy-pictured-holding-decapitated-head-syria-shock-graphic-pictures_n_5671204.html?utm_hp_ref=uk) reads

### Grandfather Of Australian Boy Pictured Holding 'DECAPITATED' Head In Syria Tells Of Shock

Decapitated? It's used as an **adjective** here. That seems strange usage to me.

***How? This way...***

> [decapitate **(verb)**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/decapitate) - **Cut off the head** of (someone)

The sentence could be - A cruel militant ***decapitates*** a soldier. This means he *cuts off* the head of the soldier.

So, once this brutal procedure is done, the head is *separated from the body* and then we can use the ***adjective*** decapitated. But then, it is **the body** that takes the adjective and **not** the head. That's how OxfordDictionaries defines the ***adjective*** decapitated in its example:

> a decapitated body

So, it is ***decapitated body*** and not the head. What do we write [*a beheaded body*](http://www.hindustantimes.com/elections2014/election-beat/beheaded-soldier-hemraj-s-village-sees-hope-in-modi/article1-1209786.aspx) or *a beheaded head?*

I would not have any problem with this headline (hypothetical)

### A shocking image of boy holding *severed head* with *decapitated body* lying nearby in the pool of blood

To prove my point further, I would cite here something authentic that I as a doctor have read and used.

Let's take the word '[amputate](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/amputated?showCookiePolicy=true)'. It means to remove an organ from the body. It's a surgical procedure to save someone's life. For instance, if you have [a diabetic foot, to prevent it spreading further, surgeons amputate that foot](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/diabetes/in-depth/amputation-and-diabetes/art-20048262) and the patient is saved. In this case, after surgery, we have ***amputated foot*** and not ***amputated patient!*** The latter simply means *dead patient!* Because you amputate a limb *from* the patient's body.

In the same way, we may have *amputated limbs* and not *amputated body*. If the surgery has been recently performed, we say, *"That's the patient of diabetic foot, operated <del>amputated.</del>"*  **Yes,** looking at the cut foot we say, *"That's the foot, amputated."* That is because the surgeon did not amputate the patient, but his foot. :)

Again, back to the question, if you cut off the head, the process is *decapitating.* After decapitating, you have *severed head* and *decapitated body* not *decapitated head.* So, would you confirm that the usage of the word is incorrect. Or am I missing something?

Thanks for reading! :)

Comment: You are correct in doubting the usage of decapitated in that sentence. It should be "severed head" since the act of "decapitation" is done to the body and not the head, the head is removed from the body (the head is not removed from the head). The head is de-bodyfied. Somehow that sounds really gruesome though. But, what's your actual question? Whether the usage is correct?

Comment: @Vincent Yes, as I said, it looks incorrect. Do you agree? *(It seems you do!)*

Comment: Yes, I agree. Let me make an answer out of my comment.

Comment: @Maulik Another mind-boggling example: *disarmed weapons* and *disarmed soldiers*. (It's rather obvious that the two *disarmed* are different. Could it be the same in our case of *decapitated*, too?) I also found a handful of *"beheaded head"* on Google Books, e.g. *"... as would forever prevent that hydra from re-growing his beheaded head."*

Comment: Additionally, I found some *"amputated patient"* examples on Google Books, too, e.g. *"... but I shall be happy to authenticate the description I have given of any Case, respecting which a newly-amputated patient, or the operator may desire further information."* -- *"The qualifications of the surgeon performing the amputation are not nearly as important as his or her interest in providing postoperative rehabilitation for the newly amputated patient."*

Comment: ***"So, kindly confirm, that usage of the word is incorrect."*** <== Many of us native English speakers naturally use that word in that way. And so, obviously that usage of the word isn't *incorrect.*

Comment: @F.E. I never thought you'd rate the question by that one line. Anyway changed.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I remember a native speaker here advising that not all Google books results are reliable. Nevertheless it happens in rare case and all I can say that this is it. In my twelve years of medical career, I've always heard, read and used amputated limbs and never amputated patient. We never killed anyone. :-)

Comment: But you didn't change the meaning of that sentence. And what I said earlier still stands. There's a big problem with your question-post: that is, you are assuming that native English speakers are wrong when they use that type of usage. You should actually be asking why so many native English speakers find that kind of usage acceptable and why they speak and write that way.

Comment: @F.E. Firstly, I don't understand how did nativeness pop in! And if I edit and put the question word to word from your comment do you think I'll ever get an answer to that? If I consider your comment, it gives me an answer that it's that way just because natives use it. Learn by heart and there's no grammar in that :-SS

Comment: That headline that you are criticizing is from a USA/UK online publication, which is written in English by writers and editors who are paid to write in more-or-less standard English for a native English speaking audience. Their style of English will often be more on the formal side than informal. Also, that sentence you are criticizing is a headline of an article, and headlines have their own way of wording stuff. And yes, simply put: English is what we the native English speakers speak.

Comment: @F.E. You mean [headlinese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese) and that style is irrelevant here. Read that they *do* have their own way but not like this. Of course, you, as a native, know much more than I do but something interesting here -http://adulted.about.com/od/howtos/tp/fivegrammartips.htm Surprisingly, I never made any of those mistakes! :)

Comment: The first word in your sentence reminds me of another error: grandfather clock. No such clocks have grandchildren. Let's found a movement to purge every mistaken use from  existence.

Comment: Why do so many people say *pair* of panties, but *a* bra? Let's educate them!

Comment: I'm going to head off for a while.

Comment: @F.E. Yes, language is defined by usage. But to say, "A professional writer wrote it, therefore it is correct" just doesn't follow. Surely it is reasonable to say that SOME use of language is incorrect, regardless of who said or wrote it. If the president of the Modern Language Association said "We was there", I'm sure if you pointed it out to him he would agree that it was an error, and not insist that because he said it, that's makes it right.

Comment: @Jay Er, you're replying to an 8 month old comment? Also, as to: *But to say, "A professional writer wrote it, therefore it is correct" just doesn't follow.* <== Did I say that?

Comment: This is yet another question assuming symmetry in English. While I agree that technically _severed head_ is better word choice than _decapitated head_ I also have no problem with the later. A _decapitated head_ has been cut off the body. A _decapitated body_ has had the head cut off. A _severed head_ head is the same as a _decapitated head_ but you wouldn't say a _severed body_! English often does not have symmetry!

Comment: @F.E. RE 8 month old comment: Sure. This question showed up as a related question when I was looking at something else. The Site Purity Nazis are always closing questions on the grounds that a question is of "poor quality" and thus will detract from the site being becoming a repository of generally-useful Q&As that future generations will look back on and treasure, so I take that to mean that all old questions are considered a permanent reference. :-) RE "did I say that?", that seemed to me the obvious intent of your comment. If that's not what you meant, okay, what did you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said in the comments, you are correct in doubting the usage of decapitated in that sentence. It should be "severed head" since the act of "decapitation" is done to the body and not the head, the head is removed from the body (the head is not removed from the head). The head is de-bodyfied. Somehow that sounds really gruesome though.

Comment: The head is decorporated.

Comment: That makes it sound even more gruesome. It looks like it already has another usage though: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/decorporation

Comment: It's somewhat redundant and perhaps not ideal—I wouldn't recommend the phrase myself—but it's common enough in corpora that I'm reluctant to characterize it as an error.

Answer (score 7):

'Decapitated head' is actually more common than 'decapitated body' ([Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=body%20decapitated%2Cdecapitated%20body%2Chead%20decapitated%2Cdecapitated%20head%2Chand%20decapitated%2Cdecapitated%20hand%2Cdecapitated%20foot%2Cfoot%20decapitated&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbody%20decapitated%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdecapitated%20body%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chead%20decapitated%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdecapitated%20head%3B%2Cc0)), but 'body [be] decapitated' is more common than 'head [be] decapitated' ([Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=head%20be_INF%20decapitated%2Cbody%20be_INF%20decapitated&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t3%3B%2Chead%20be_INF%20decapitated%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhead%20is%20decapitated%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhead%20was%20decapitated%3B%2Cc0%3B.t3%3B%2Cbody%20be_INF%20decapitated%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bbody%20was%20decapitated%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbody%20is%20decapitated%3B%2Cc0))

I saw headlines like this and didn't think twice about it.  (Linguistically, that is; emotionally I am deeply worried about decapitated bodies (or heads).) I think the meaning has extended beyond 'Cut off the head of (someone)' (but not as far an any other body part - there were no hits for 'hand/foot decapitated', 'decapitated hand/foot').

Comment: Should the word mean 'cut off from the body', I would not have any problem with it. It explicitly means 'detached/cut head' and hence, it should not be used with 'head'.

Comment: Any number of linguistics websites will tell you that 'etymology is not destiny'; in other words, what a word originally meant, or what its component parts can be understood to mean now, does not fix its meaning for all time. Meanings of words change, including many words we use every day without a second thought (eg next month is literally 'seventh month').

Comment: I really wonder if we'll *ever* say, *amputated patient* instead of *amputated limbs* or for that sake *beheaded head*

Comment: According to Google Ngram (which I can't link to) some people do! (not very many, but some)

Answer (score 4):

There is no reason at all to feel ill at ease with that headline - at least from a linguistic point of view!

Although the head itself can hardly be said to be decapitated, neither is a pair of scissors left-handed. What happens is a common construction called a [**transferred epithet**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypallage) or **hypallage**.

Some examples include:

> A left-handed pair of scissors: *the user is left-handed*
>   Those were happy days: *the people living those days were happy*
>   I had a restless night: *I was restless, not the night*

Comment: +1 You made the point so well, that I think we should keep your decapitated head alive after your body leaves us, forever generating SE answers.

Answer (score 2):

Maulik, you are correct to be ill-at-ease with the article title. Vincent is correct. The Latin basis for the word is: *de-* (expressing removal) + *caput, capit-* ‘head'. The correct usage should be "severed head", not "decapitated head". The second, which I see all the time in the middle- to low-rank media outlets, is grammatically redundant. This is the same reason why "... he killed him dead..." is incorrect.

Note some of the responses here defending the error with the two most popular defenses: that the error is common in everyday usage and that language changes. However I am willing to bet that the people who use it incorrectly are not thinking in either of those two modes when making the error.

You always hear people state that the purpose of language is communication. However another even more important purpose is as a tool to articulate the world in which we live. The word "decapitation" is one articulation level higher than "sever". When both are used as exact synonyms, language loses articulation and becomes less nuanced. This is an increasing problem with poor state of language education and the propagation of language errors through mass media.

As an English Language Learner, continue to use the same level of rigor in your use of the English language. It is wholly appropriate. Don't let anyone tell you otherwise.

Comment: +1 for your frank opinion. Though I did not get your last paragraph. :) you may paraphrase it for me to convey the message.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question but a point of view.

Comment: Laure, the answer was clearly stated in the first paragraph of my response.

Comment: @Laure in fact, this is an answer ***with*** a point of view1 :)

Comment: @MaulikV Yes, indeed.  "The correct usage should be" advising against popular use of the phrase is definitely a personal point of view, and is not neutral. Snailplane's comment *I wouldn't recommend the phrase myself* is a much better way to say it without moral judgement. In the end it's a matter of personal opinion. And we're back into the same old debate about prescriptive and descriptive.

Comment: I disagree with the conclusion, for reasons that have nothing to do with everyday usage or the fact that language changes. But I'm still giving this a +1 for making the case so clearly that one can thoughtfully _choose_ how to use a word rather than thoughtlessly follow the flock.

Comment: A decapitated body makes sense. A severed head makes sense. A decapitated head? It's a strange head indeed that can have its head removed.

Comment: That was my first post here. Today I would answer that question without the proselytizing. However, considering my academic background, language training, and the contemporary context, my feelings have not changed. ; )

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you are looking for is disembodied.  The head without the body is disembodied. The body without the head is decapitated.

Comment: _Disembodied_ suggests that whatever it is is massless - such as a _disembodied voice_, for instance. A _disembodied head_ seems infelicitous to me.

Comment: The phrase 'disembodied head' does exist (can't link to Google Ngrams in a comment) but I agree that it seems infelicitous - one does not remove a body from the head; one removes a head from the body. (I suppose you *could* remove the body part by part, but that's the long way round.)